# Trying to upload a PDF file in my form in React component but getting {} when I use setFormData

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, file-upload, react-state

I am trying to create a form in react with a file upload functionality. I have written a *handleFileUpload* function which is triggered when the user selects the file that needs to be uploaded. The file is getting logged in the console correctly wehn I use `e.target.files[0]`, however when I try to set the file to the state or *formData* in my case, the value of file in formData is always {}. Any kind of help would be highly appreciated.

I have tried using form `encType='multipart/form-data'` but to no avail. I even tried storing the file in a seperate state using useState but again got empty braces when I try to do *setState* with `e.target.files[0]`.

This is the code for my component where I am taking the user's file that needs to be uploaded using an input tag in a form.

```
const AddNewContract = ({createNewContract}) => {
    const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
        file: null
      });

      const {
        file
    } = formData

    const handleFileUpload = e => {
      e.preventDefault();
      const temp_file = e.target.files[0];
      console.log(temp_file);

      setFormData({ ...formData, file: temp_file });
    }


    return (
        <Fragment>
            <Container >
            <form className='form' onSubmit={args => onSubmit(args)} >
            <p className='lead'>
             <i className='fas fa-user' /> Enter the new contract details.
            </p>

        <div className='form-group'>
        <label htmlFor="clientName">Upload contract PDF </label>
          <input type='file' name='file' onChange={args => handleFileUpload(args)} />
        </div>

        <input type='submit' className='btn btn-primary my-1' value='Add Contract' />
      </form>
      </Container>
      <div>
        {JSON.stringify(formData)}
      </div>
        </Fragment>


    )
}

AddNewContract.propTypes = {
    createNewContract: PropTypes.func.isRequired
}

export default connect(null, {createNewContract})(withRouter(AddNewContract));
```

I expect the *formData* state to have the file as the value of file but instead I get `{"file":{}}`. The `console.log(temp_file)` command gives me :

> File {name: "Resume.pdf", lastModified: 1571412334151, lastModifiedDate: Fri Oct 18 2019 11:25:34 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time), webkitRelativePath: "", size: 128128, …}

which is the whole file contents and exactly what I want to store in my state or *formData* but it doesn't work for some reason. Please help me find the problem here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what is happening here is that when you are printing the formData you are getting 
`{file:{}}` empty even though you have selected a file because the file is not a JSON object so doing JSON.Stringify() will not print the keys of the file.

Instead I would suggest that if you want to print the content of the formData use this function.

```
const getFormDataContent = (formData = {}) => {
    const { file } = formData;
    let keys = Object.keys(formData);
    keys = keys.filter(key => key !== "file");
    const data = {
      lastModified: file.lastModified,
      lastModifiedDate: file.lastModifiedDate,
      name: file.name,
      size: file.size,
      type: file.type
    };
    const fileData = { file: data };
    keys.forEach(key => {
      fileData[key] = formData[key];
    });
    return fileData;
  };
```

and then print it using this JSON.Stringify like this

`<div>{JSON.stringify(getFormDataContent(formData))}</div>`

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. Didn’t realize that the file object was not in JSON format.

Answer (score 0):

```
const [formData, setFormData] = useState([]);

...

setFormData([e.target.files[0]]);
```